# Assessing and interpreting the results of a multinomial logistic regression in R

Tags: regression, r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-probit

I run a multinomial logistic regression. The input data are given below:

[image]

And the results are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78110101/how-to-create-dummy-variables-for-a-multinomial-logistic-regression?noredirect=1#comment137705748_78110101).

```
> summary(factors)
Call:
multinom(formula = Juice_knwolege ~ Age + Gender + Education + 
    Access_to_resources, data = Juice)

Coefficients:
       (Intercept)       Age GenderMale EducationSecondary EducationTertiary
No       134.56898 -5.029697   314.1956          -15.96461         -86.39731
Use To   -99.23136  3.927217   122.5766           46.57026         -10.86831
       Access_to_resourcesYes
No                  -74.66129
Use To             -235.86296

Std. Errors:
        (Intercept)          Age   GenderMale EducationSecondary EducationTertiary
No     3.208056e+02 5.675463e+01 9.063978e-27       4.973037e-25      5.999055e-63
Use To 4.973037e-25 2.436788e-23 4.973037e-25       4.973037e-25     8.090522e-121
       Access_to_resourcesYes
No               3.208056e+02
Use To           4.390071e-29

Residual Deviance: 0.0001886377 
AIC: 24.00019
```

I would like to establish whether the results are correct given the input dataset and how to interpret them in laymen terms. What does Yes mean in the results as reference in relation to No and Use To? The same apply to male in relation to female used as reference, primary as reference in relation to other education categories and No access to resources as a reference category in relation to yes. How do i interpret the reference with comparison to other categories and what does that really mean?

My understanding is that the results must speak to the input dataset, for example, there is seven Yes and only four No and one Use To for the first column of juice practice. This means more people recorded Yes or can make Juice compared to those who cannot or Use To make juice (No and Use To). But I am failing to make sense of the results and contextualize it in a sensible way.

Here is my interpretation; those who can make Juice (Yes) are 134.56898 times more that those who cannot make Juice (No) and those who can (Yes) are -99.23136 times less than those who Use To (looking at the intercept).

Female can make juice (Yes) 314.1956 more times than males who cannot (No), and females Use to make juice 122.5766 more times than the male? This does not make sense given that there is no Use To for female and only one Use To for male when I look at the input data?

Those who can make Juice (Yes/ref) are -15.96461 times less than those who cannot make Juice with Primary education (ref) compared to those who can with secondary education, and those who use to are 46.57026 times more compared to those who can?

I would also like to find out why are some values negative and others positive?
And how do I interpret the age results?

Comment: Your second linked post has been removed. Are you able to include model output in your current question?

Comment: The linked StackOverflow question has an image of a table with 4 households. Is that all of your dataset? If yes, perhaps it would be sufficient to make plots and describe any patterns you observe?

Comment: I have added the model output to the question. This is a test dataset, a pilot with only a few household however my total study sample is 385 household. For now I am testing the model with the few household.

Answer (score 2):

In general, odds ratios tend to provide the most straightforward interpretation when presenting to a non-statistical or clinical audience and are widely. Currently your estimates are on the log-odds scale so you will need to exponentiate your estimates and confidence intervals.

Your interpretation is close but I believe is backwards. The coefficient is showing the difference in the log-odds of each outcome level (no and use too) compared to the reference (yes). The sign attached to the coefficient is essentially showing the 'direction of effect'.

Here is a useful resource for interpreting OR/RR - https://www.nature.com/articles/pcrj20006.pdf

Looking at your dataset it seems you only have one observation with outcome level 'use too' which can cause an issue with model accuracy and explains the incredibly large coefficients. If it does not cause you to lose too much detail in your outcome variable, I might suggest collapsing the 'no' and 'use too' levels to create a dichotomous outcome and use binary logistic regression.

Comment: Does collapsing mean getting rid of that one value of Use To and instead only have Yes and No, or what exactly does it mean? Where do I put that one particular value of Use To?

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus Collapsing just means to combine the 'no' and 'use to' groups so the outcome would be yes vs. no/use to

Comment: Let me try your suggestions. need to use both Multinomial and Binary logistic for my study. Does exponentiating my estimates and confidence intervals means converting the results to odd ratios? Is there a way to do a multinomial and have results in odd ratios which are easy to interpret and not log odds?

Comment: I tampered with the data to see if there will be a difference in the coefficient, I made the observation for Use To 3 and the coefficient is still large, what does this mean?

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus I think it still comes down to an issue of small sample size and quasi-separation in your data. Trying using Firth's logistic regression with the brglm and brglm2 packages. This is a bias-reduction method for binary logistic regression using a penalized likelihood. Implement this by adding method="brglmFit" to your glm function.

Comment: I appreciate your kind assistance. I am a geographer with no statistical background. Indeed you are correct I figured the sample size is a factor here. According to literature Multinomial logistic regression requires a minimum of 15-20 observation for each independent variable. I tested and the coefficient became in the range of-1 and -0/0 and 1 etc. Next step is now to exponentiate your estimates and confidence intervals. Any guidance, tutorials on how to do this building on my existing code?

Comment: @AmeliaNicodemus You're welcome! To get exponentiated coefficients and confidence intervals you can use the base functions - exp(coef(model.name) and exp(confint(model.name). To get a cleaner looking output use the summ() function with option exp=T from the jtools package